# What is this weed and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: identification, lawn, weed-control

I have this stuff all through my lawn and garden.  Normal weed killer had no effect on it. I want it gone.

[image]

This is a section of the lawn:

[image]

This what it does in the garden when it's not mowed:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the group Justin!  Can you update your question with the weedkiller you used and how long it has been since you applied it

Comment: Short of using roundup I have tried every form of weed killer in the lawn was Scotts weed n feed in the garden I used preen slow release weed n feed short of using roundup on every individual plant I'm at a loss it's all connected together underground and last application was over 4 weeks ago when the 3" layer of mulch was put down and as you see it came back

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your question if you want to add extra information. Do not post them as answers. Please see the [tour] and [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like a type of sorrel, along the lines of

https://gobotany.newenglandwild.org/species/rumex/acetosella/

[This PDF from davis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://wric.ucdavis.edu/information/natural%2520areas/wr_R/Rumex_crispus-obtusifolius.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjG-OvVhbzUAhUBYj4KHRD-Bg8QFggtMAM&usg=AFQjCNFkpjRAB9h6NRao6DVhfofmowqubw&sig2=aJ7XhboJGnRyj4fcI0igHw) has some detailed info on how to control two rumex species.  This might be a good place to start.

That said, sorrel is quite tasty, so if it's one of the edible species, you could harvest it (though the weedkiller already applied might negate that option).

Answer (score 1):

The plants seem large and it seems just few plants. Why not using the manual method? Quick and most effective.

Comment: It's not just one plant it's all through the garden's and lawn killing off the grass I cleared the plants around it to get a good pic of it I weeded it 4 weeks ago and mulched and treated it at the same time

Comment: My answer was based on just the first (and only) photo, where plants were on chips. With the other images, I think redoing the lawn is the quick solution. But.... doesn't let the weed to make seeds (like in third photo), cut them earlier, and it will simplify the removal.

Answer (score 1):

Its French sorrel- quite tasty, lemony if I remember- weed kill it(something systemic) with a touch of stump killer/brush wood killer- paint it on when young and sappy with a brush and wait three weeks- remember its got a very long tap roots so digging it out has to be done when the ground is soft think about 12 inches or more in length if you want to go for that option.